# Problem with tikz-pgf and \pgfmathabs

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3

This is a follow up question to [Problem with pgfmathsetmacro in foreach loop with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73914/problem-with-pgfmathsetmacro-in-foreach-loop-with-pgfplots).

In short I also want to use `\pgfmathabs` to get the absolute value of a number in that example (with `\i` as input). But I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 8.

--- TeX said ---
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 8.
--- HELP ---
No help available
```

I tried to compose a MWE to isolate this problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\edef\test{\noexpand \node at (0,0) {\pgfmathabs{-2}};} 
\test
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Adding a `\noexpand` before the `\pgfmathabs` solves the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\pgfmathabs` (and the other `pgfmath` macros, including the general `\pgfmathparse`) are [not expandable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69962/why-is-there-no-pgfmath-macro-that-expands-directly-to-the-result), so you'll have to do the calculation step before the `\edef` definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\pgfmathabs{-2}
\edef\test{\noexpand \node at (0,0) {\pgfmathresult};} 
\test
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

As Joseph suggests in the comment and in the linked answer, you can use the LaTeX3 FPU as an alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\fpabs}[1]{\fp_eval:n{abs(#1)}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\edef\test{\noexpand \node at (0,0) {\fpabs{-2}};} 
\test
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or you can do it inside the node by preventing the expansion `\noexpand\pgfmathabs{-2}\noexpand\pgfmathresult`

Comment: An alternative would be to use the LaTeX3 FPU as in the linked question, with a definition such as `\usepackage{expl3}\ExplSyntaxOn\newcommand{\fpabs}[1]{\fp_eval:n{abs(#1)}}\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks! I've incorporated the suggestion into my answer

Comment: I tried the LaTeX3 FPU version, but get the following error: `ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\fpabs #1->\fp_eval:n 
                      {abs(#1)}
l.13 ...\test{\noexpand \node at (0,0) {\fpabs{-2}
                                                  };}`

Comment: @student Do you have the most recent version of the LaTeX3 FPU code?

Comment: @AndrewStacey Just installed the latest version now it works!

Comment: Actually, we also have `\fp_abs:n {#1}` which is equivalent to `\fp-eval:n { abs(#1) }`.